# Validating value as a number in a TextBox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am binding a `float?` property to a `TextBox` in a WPF application. I also have `ValidatesOnDataErrors` in place.

When I enter an invalid non-numeric value, the border of the `TextBox` turns into a different color, because it cannot convert the value into a `float`. So the value binds to `null`.

My question is - how can I stop it from binding to `null`? I really want to give an error such as, "Please enter numeric values only". Thank You.

Comment: if you want to show message just put event textchanged for the textbox and check for valid number there.

Answer (score 0):

Style is the best approach for data entry validation. All you need to do is copy this style to your Window or UserControl.
Note: I use ToolTips, but you can use your own approach to show up the notification to users:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Pink"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Polygon Points="9,9 9,0 0,0" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                     ToolTip="Please enter numeric values only"/>
                        <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="valAdorner" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <Border BorderBrush="red" BorderThickness="1" />
                        </AdornedElementPlaceholder>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```